# What are my options with a downloaded Rackspace cloud image?

Tags: linux, cloud, rackspace-cloud, data-recovery, forensic-analysis

I've got an unresponsive Rackspace slice that has defied all attempts at accessing. I created an emergency image from this and deleted it, downloading the files that compromise the image to a local source. There are a number of files / assets I would still like to recover from this server if possible but not sure exactly what I can do with the image files, if anything.

Here's the files I have, for what its worth:

```
emergency_########_######_cloudserver########.tar.gz.0 (5gb)
emergency_########_######_cloudserver########.tar.gz.1 (5gb)
emergency_########_######_cloudserver########.tar.gz.2 (5gb)
emergency_########_######_cloudserver########.tar.gz.3 (50mb)
emergency_########_######_cloudserver########.yml (25kb)
```

Is it possible to mount this image as a drive? Are there other forensic recovery options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you get after putting the .tar.gz back together and unpacking it results in a disk image, then you should be able to recover files from it.

To begin with, for best results you should be working from a Linux system, with plenty of drive space available (50GB or more). I'm not sure if this is even possible with Windows.

First put the file back together:

```
cat emergency*.tar.gz.* > image.tar.gz
```

Now unpack it:

```
tar -zxvf image.tar.gz
```

What comes next depends on what was in the tarball. Hopefully it's a single file containing a disk image. In that case, inspect it with:

```
kpartx -l *imagefile*
```

(Where *imagefile* is the name of the disk image file that came out of the tarball.)

You should see what looks like a partition table. If all looks well with the partition table, run:

```
kpartx -v -a *imagefile*
```

This will map the partitions in the image to /dev/mapper/loop0p*.

You should then be able to mount these partitions and look at their contents. Remember to mount the filesystems read-only (`-o ro`) to prevent further damage.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this almost definitely belongs on ServerFault.

The "emergency" files are showing up as ".tar.gz" in the file extension, which tells me that they *should* be tar archives that you can extract like a zip file. If you're on Windows, download 7-zip from http://7-zip.org and you should be able to open them.

I'm not sure what you'll find within since I've never been a Rackspace customer; but I hear that they have "fanatical support" so it may be within your power to ask *them* about their backup files and how to access them....

Best of luck.

Comment: I use rackspace and will vouch for their support...nothing but good experiences here.  Open a ticket a my.rackspace.com