# Server Move From Rackspace to AWS Cloud

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, git, rackspace

I'm wondering specifically is there way to migrate Centos6.3 server from Rackspace to AWS cloud, Server image is 268.92 GB Uncompressed.

I've done the sync processes before and it didn't work so I wanted to spin up the exact same instance. I also tried the newer libraries of the platform we are running but it failed.

This is essentially what i need to run https://github.com/knmnyn/ParsCit. Is there's another way to get that running on the dev machine to updated the repo on? can anyone Help me with this?

Comment: is the existing CentOS 6.3 machine a physical or virtual machine? I assume virtual because you said "server image is ... GB".

Comment: could you elaborate on the sync process you tried before which didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

The poorly named [AWS Application Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/application-migration-service/) based on CloudEndure is probably your best bet to migrate a server to AWS. It doesn't migrate applications, as such, it migrates virtual machines. The previous recommendation was [AWS SMS Server Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/), but the AWS website says that it's going end of life in March '22.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a virtual machine in [our Public Cloud](https://docs.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-servers/quickstart/), try to export your server image and download it, then import to AWS EC2

1. export, then download the image (VHD).
   this is well described in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/888393/49308)
2. upload the image (VHD) to AWS S3
3. [import to AWS EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html)